# Probability of the second product to be a failure if the first was success from two boxes

Tags: probability

There are two boxes with products. We know that the the products in the first box are perfect, but the products in the second are $\dfrac{1}{4}$ of them a failure. We choose a random box and a random product and we see that it is a success and we put it back in the box. What is the probability a second product from the same box will be a failure?

I don't know how to approach this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** This is a conditional probability problem. Calculate the probability that the first product is from the non-perfect box. If you have that, multiply that by $\frac14$ to know the probability that the product from the same box is a failure.